# Pycharm 4.5.3 copy paste bug

Tags: pycharm

I'm on Pycharm 4.5.3 on Ubuntu . Paste operations from other applications  to pycharm works well but it seems to fail vice versa. Similarly within pycharm  window simple Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V doesn't seem to work.

I have to paste-from-History every-time and it is annoying. Is there a know fix for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a alert regarding Open JDK 7 after installing Oracle JDK the issue seem to have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having issues with copy-paste on PyCharm on Linux for a while.  And it's hugely irritating.  However, after typing "clipboard" into PyCharm settings I think I may have figured out the issue.

While copy-paste with the Linux clipboard works the first time, soon after you can only copy-paste from within PyCharm.

So, when you type "clipboard" into PyCharm settings, you'll see there is a "Paste from X clipboard" Keymap shortcut that is defaulted to "Button2 Click".

Which means, middle mouse pastes from the Linux clipboard into PyCharm ...